# Detect if hard disk is being accessed or not

Tags: c#, hard-drive, system.diagnostics, led

I am trying to make a very simple hard disk access monitor **to work like those embedded LEDs that blink according to drive usage**. That LED REALLY helps me, but the laptop I am using does not have it. =[

So, I've made a simple tray icon application, but I don't know how to determine that variable of disk access.

I've searched for it and found something like **System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter**, but I have no idea on using it for my task.

If there is another solution, I'd also appreciate! =]
Thanks.

Oh! I almost forgot, it needs to detect ANY and EVERY access to the hard drive.. I've tested an application out there (with the exact same supposed function), but after some tests I could easily realize it was missing some accesses, mainly when you executed a new program.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: How does that LED help you, really? Which hard drive are you interested in? If its the drive with the O/S then you might as well paste a green button on your toolbar as the O/S drive is pretty much in use non-stop. To get a better feel for the actual activity I recommend you try Process Monitor and look at the file access tab. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: @Igor It helps me by indicating the system is performing some disk task.. for instance, when I need to update or install something and it seems to be frozen, that led is the most practical indicator of such any actual activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a hard disk activity monitor sample application written in VB.NET.  It's fairly simple so you should have no problem converting it to c#.

The idea is to use two Performance Counters, "Disk Read Bytes/sec" and "Disk Write Bytes/sec" for "LogicalDisk"

```
 ReadCounter = New PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "Disk Read Bytes/sec", "_Total") 
 WriteCounter = New PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "Disk Write Bytes/sec", "_Total")
```

And then in your main loop (which needs to be threaded) you call `NextValue` to determine if there is disk activity.

```
R = ReadCounter.NextValue 
W = WriteCounter.NextValue
```

The full source code is [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disk-Activity-Task-bar-af8ae245) on Microsoft's site.

Comment: awesome!
I adapted and executed both VB and C#.. they blink perfectly in sync. All I needed were your code snippets! =]